# Continuity of multivariable piecewise function (sin, cos)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\ (x-2y)\sin(xy)}{(xy^2 + x)},& y\ne0\wedge xy\ne-1\\
 x^2,& y=0\vee xy=-1.
\end{cases}  $$

I should analyze continuity in each domain point and justify my answer.

First, I analyzed domain.

if $x=y=0$, the function is not defined, so the domain would be all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Are there any more points that should be excluded from the domain? I do not know how to calculate this analytically. How should I do it?

I tried to calculate $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{(x-2y)\sin(xy))}{xy^2 + x}$$

but was not able to solve it. I tried dividing both numerator and denominator by $y^2$ or $x-2y$, but could not get a result. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: $x = y = 0$ is included in the case $y = 0$ or $xy = -1$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: thanks for your answer. How would you go on solving the limit I wrote? I tried but could not do it.

Comment: @pablofiumara: Your one case does not make sense how could the ordered pair $(x,y)$ ever equal the real number $-1$ ?

Comment: Check again the definition. Beyond the obvious typo ($(x,y)$ must be $xy$) the quotient of the first case is undefined when $x = 0$.

Comment: @rt6: You're right. It was a typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Thanks. Unfortunately, I do not understand how I can use what you are telling me to start solving the problem.

Comment: @pablofiumara: Let's just back up for a second and take stock. A definition for the domain of a multivariable function is a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that for every point $(x,y)\in D $ there exists exactly one point $z=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ that the function maps to. Usually we are only worried about points where the function is not well defined. So the $z$ value in that case does not exist. In the first case this is only a problem when the denominator is zero. So $xy^2+x\neq 0$

Comment: For the limit to exist, the value that the function approaches from every conceivable path towards $(0,0)$ must be equal. You could try out a few specific paths like $x=y^2$ or $x=y$. This will make it a single variable limit problem. If these fail, you could always use the $\epsilon-\delta$ defn of continuity. From the 2nd case in your function, we can see $f(0,0)=0$ the limit must equal the function value for the function to be continuous

Comment: @rt6: Thank you for your answer. It seems the strategy to solve this kind of exercises is to take a path making the problem a single variable limit problem. My problem is that many advanced books (such as those which talk about multivariable limits) have only few examples. Besides, I could not find a similar example to my problem here in math.stackexchange.com